# What is the spark cluster size that would be required to process 400 Billion records of 3 columns?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with 400 billion records with 3 columns. I am trying to filter the data based on a column value. What is the optimal cluster size that would be required to process this data without getting out of memory error.

```
df1 = spark.read_csv("fileA")
df2 = spark.read_csv("fileB")

cross_join_df = df1.crossJoin(df2) # 400 Billion records

df = cross_join_df.filter(colA > 0.6)
df.write.format("parquet").path("<path>)
```

Comment: How big are each of your records? This is a key point, as each record being 1 bit and each record being 2TB are vastly different.

Comment: Two columns contain 8 to 12 alpha numeric characters each, and one column contains a float value of 8 digits with 7 decimals in it.